# How can i simplify these methods to avoid duplicate code?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to simplify these methods? They are the same except for a different method being called.

```
private async Task ChangePresence(bool args, int voteId)
    {
        if (GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting != null)
        {
            _spinnerVisible = true;

            await AgendaItemsDetailState.ChangePresence(args, GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID,
                AgendaItemId, voteId);
            await AgendaState.GetAgendaItem(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);
            await AgendaItemsDetailState.GetVotesList(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);

            _spinnerVisible = false;
        }
    }

    private async Task VoteFor(bool args, int voteId)
    {
        if (GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting != null)
        {
            _spinnerVisible = true;

            await AgendaItemsDetailState.ChangeVoteFor(args, GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID,
                AgendaItemId, voteId, GeneralMeetingState.IsUserOwner);
            await AgendaState.GetAgendaItem(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);
            await AgendaItemsDetailState.GetVotesList(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);

            _spinnerVisible = false;
        }
    }

    private async Task VoteAgainst(bool args, int voteId)
    {
        if (GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting != null)
        {
            _spinnerVisible = true;

            await AgendaItemsDetailState.ChangeVoteAgainst(args, GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID,
                AgendaItemId, voteId, GeneralMeetingState.IsUserOwner);
            await AgendaState.GetAgendaItem(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);
            await AgendaItemsDetailState.GetVotesList(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);

            _spinnerVisible = false;
        }
    }

    private async Task ChangeVoteAbstinence(bool args, int voteId)
    {
        if (GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting != null)
        {
            _spinnerVisible = true;

            await AgendaItemsDetailState.ChangeVoteAbstinence(args, GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID,
                AgendaItemId, voteId, GeneralMeetingState.IsUserOwner);
            await AgendaState.GetAgendaItem(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);
            await AgendaItemsDetailState.GetVotesList(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);

            _spinnerVisible = false;
        }
    }
```

I was looking into passing a method as a parameter and using Action<bool, int> but i couldn't figure it out. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: give some code about call these methods> please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea to pass `Action<bool, int>` seems to be almost the right one. The easiest one would be passing just `Func<Task>`. Something along this lines:

```
// TODO - give more meaningful name
private async Task DoSomething(Func<Task> something)
{
    if (GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting != null)
    {
        _spinnerVisible = true;

        await something();
        await AgendaState.GetAgendaItem(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);
        await AgendaItemsDetailState.GetVotesList(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);

        _spinnerVisible = false;
    }
}
```

And methods changed to the following:

```
private async Task ChangePresence(bool args, int voteId)
{
    await DoSomething(() => AgendaItemsDetailState.ChangePresence(args, GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId, voteId))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps:

```
private Task ChangePresence(bool args, int voteId) =>
    Execute(() => AgendaItemsDetailState.ChangePresence(args, GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId, voteId));

private Task VoteFor(bool args, int voteId) =>
    Execute(() => AgendaItemsDetailState.ChangeVoteFor(args, GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId, voteId, GeneralMeetingState.IsUserOwner));

private Task VoteAgainst(bool args, int voteId) =>
    Execute(() => AgendaItemsDetailState.ChangeVoteAgainst(args, GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId, voteId, GeneralMeetingState.IsUserOwner));

private Task ChangeVoteAbstinence(bool args, int voteId) =>
    Execute(() => AgendaItemsDetailState.ChangeVoteAbstinence(args, GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId, voteId, GeneralMeetingState.IsUserOwner));

private async Task Execute(Func<Task> func)
{
    if (GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting != null)
    {
        _spinnerVisible = true;

        await func();
        await AgendaState.GetAgendaItem(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);
        await AgendaItemsDetailState.GetVotesList(GeneralMeetingState.GeneralMeeting.ID, AgendaItemId);

        _spinnerVisible = false;
    }
}
```